# How can this problem be defined formally?

Tags: equities, portfolio, correlation, scenario-analysis

Let's consider a straightforward example in which I possess a portfolio consisting of two stocks:

$
R(t) = S_{1}(t) \cdot x_1 + S_{2}(t) \cdot x_2,
$

Here, $t$ represents the time index, $R(t)$ symbolizes the portfolio's value in terms of dollars, $x_i$ indicates the weight of stock $i \in [1,2]$, and $[S_{1}(t),S_{2}(t)]$ denote two correlated stock prices, exhibiting the following dynamics:

$
\frac{dS_{1}(t)}{S_{1}(t)} = \mu_{1} dt + \sqrt{1-\rho^2} \sigma_{1} dW_{1}(t) + \rho \sigma_{1} dW_{2}(t), \\
\frac{dS_{2}(t)}{S_{2}(t)} = \mu_{2} dt + \sigma_{2} dW_{2}(t).
$

Assuming a forecasting horizon $H > T$, I can employ numerical simulations to predict potential future portfolio values $R(h)$ for all $h \in [T,H]$.

Now, let's suppose that at time $T$, I'm privy to insider information suggesting an impending price drop for stock $S_2(h)$. Specifically, I have knowledge that the price $S_2(h)$ will undoubtedly be less than a constant $S_2(h) = K$ for a known time $h$ in the future. By excluding scenarios that don't meet this condition, I can calculate the expected portfolio value given this scenario. While I can perform numerical computations, defining this context formally remains a challenge.

Therefore, my inquiries are as follows:

1. How can I analytically define this scenario?
2. How can I formally define the stock price conditional to this scenario?
3. Would applying Girsanov's theorem and altering probabilities be necessary?
4. How can I define the portfolio value conditional to this scenario?
5. Could you recommend literature that delves into similar problems?

I welcome your input in refining my understanding.

Comment: Are you required to keep $S_2$ in the portfolio?

Comment: yes, I keep it in the portfolio anyway.

Comment: There is a name for this technique, where you posit a stochastic process, but then you remove all trajectories meeting a specified condition, resulting in another stochastic process, which is a kind of biased version of the first.

Comment: @nbbo2 do you know the name of such technique? Can you give me some references?

Comment: The only time I saw it mentioned was in the article *Survival* by Stephen J. Brown, William N. Goetzmann and Stephen A. Ross, The Journal of Finance, Jul 1995. It may just be called "conditioning" but that is a commonly used term with many other meanings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event that the second stock price is less than a constant $K$ at the time $h$ is mathematically described by $\{S_2(h)< K\}$.

The first stock price, at the time $t\in [T,H]$, given the event is
$$S_{1}(t) \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{S_2(h)< K\}}$$

where $\mathbf{1}_{\{ \}}$ is the indicator function.

The value of the portfolio, at the time $t\in [T,H]$, given the event is
$$\left(S_{1}(t) \cdot x_1 + S_{2}(t) \cdot x_2\right)\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{S_2(h)< K\}}$$

The expected value of the portfolio, at the time $s$ such that $T\le s \le h \le H$ and $T \le s \le t \le H$ , is then equal to
$$\begin{align}
V(s) &:=\mathbb{E}\left(\left(S_{1}(t) \cdot x_1 + S_{2}(t) \cdot x_2\right)\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{S_2(h)< K\}}| \mathcal{F}_s\right) \\
&=x_1\mathbb{E}\left(S_{1}(t)  \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{S_2(h)< K\}}| \mathcal{F}_s\right)  + x_2\mathbb{E}\left(S_{2}(t) \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{S_2(h)< K\}}| \mathcal{F}_s\right) \tag{1}
\end{align}$$

The second term of $(1)$ is relatively like a put on $S_2$, you can compute it easily for example by changing to the measure $S_2$-neutral.

The calculation of the first term of $(1)$ requires a double integral (it is possible to write the result as a 2-dimensional normal probability distribution). The calculation is a little cumbersome but not difficule, I let you to do it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your considerate reply. I apologize for any confusion – I have actually made an edit to my question. There was a typo: the scenario involves the second stock price being less than a constant, rather than the second stock price being less than the first stock price.

Comment: @Barbab I modified the answer for your modified question.